# Why is the Frequency Tool in ArcGIS so Fast and Efficient?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, geoprocessing, performance

Why is the [Frequency tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001w000000) in ArcGIS is so fast and efficient?

Is it possible to make my own Frequency Tool with similar performance (in python)?

I tried to do some based on python dictionary and searchCursor but when I have more than 100,000 records to analyse it takes a long time.

Comment: If the reason you are looking to do this is to get Frequency functionality (which [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001w000000) says requires Advanced) with a Basic (formerly known as ArcView) license, then take a look at [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) with case_field(s) - so far I have always been able to use that in its place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because the internal implementation uses a lower level API (ArcObjects) and a compiled language (C++) and likely has some other optimizations not exposed through arcpy.

Also in arcpy the old cursors tend to be slow; if you are at 10.1 try the [`arcpy.da`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000008000000) (data access module) cursors.

If you want help with your code, post it.

Comment: Thanks, I improved my script with arcpy.da and works faster.